# Изменение определённых символов из переменной Javascript при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, javascript

Есть переменная Javascript:

> `var txt = "ABCDEFGHIJK"`

Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку, в этой переменной буквы 'ABEIJ' заменились на цифры 3. Как можно это сделать? Подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирайте, может, кто лучше варианты предложит.

http://jsfiddle.net/n5x9hkvq/

http://jsfiddle.net/n5x9hkvq/1/

Comment: Класс. Спасибо.